# java turtle recursion

Tags: java, recursion, turtle-graphics

I need to write a method that draw T's in circle.

int s= length of T
int c= amount of T's to draw and the degree to turn each T

this is my code:

```
public static void r(int s,int c)
    {

        t.penDown();
        t.forward(s/2);
        t.left(90);
        t.forward(s/4);
        t.right(180);
        t.forward((s/4)*2);
        t.right(180);
        t.forward(s/4);
        t.left(90);
        t.forward(s/2);
        t.left(360/c);


    }
```

int s = length of line
int c= numbers of T's to draw (and the degree to turn each time)

what is drawn is: a 4 circled T's 
this method is called in recursion and i can't find any stoping condition to this method
because the int c paramater can change beacuse it's the angle of turn but it needs to change cause thats my stoping parmater.

any help?

Comment: Why not use a loop to call r() a fixed number or times?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your explanation that you're trying to avoid changing the parameters of `r()`, you can use a recursive method of an inner class to solve this problem:

```
public static void r(Turtle t, int s, int c) {

    class InnerClass {

        private void r_recursive(Turtle t, int s, int c, int m) {
            if (m == 0) {
                return;
            }

            t.penDown();

            t.forward(s / 2);
            t.left(90);
            t.forward(s / 4);
            t.right(180);
            t.forward(s / 2);
            t.right(180);
            t.forward(s / 4);
            t.right(90);
            t.backward(s / 2);

            t.penUp();
            t.left(c);

            r_recursive(t, s, c, m - c);
        }
    }

    new InnerClass().r_recursive(t, s, c, 360);
}
```

With the invocation:

```
Turtle bob = new Turtle();

r(bob, 200, 30);
```

You should get:

[image]